# Laravel: Combining multiple query scopes on nested relationships without overriding the previous ones

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relationships, scopes

I've got the following database structure for an online learning platform: A `course` consists of `modules`. A `module` consists of `lessons` and `tasks`. There are user specific information for each of these elements with the respective relationships defined on each model:

```
class Course extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('start_at', 'end_at');
    }

    public function modules() {
        return $this->hasMany(Module::class);
    }

    // ...
}

class Module extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('start_at', 'end_at');
    }

    public function lessons() {
        return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
    }

    public function tasks() {
        return $this->hasMany(Lesson::class);
    }
}

class Lesson extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('favourite', 'completed_at');
    }
}

class Task extends Model {
    public function user() {
        return $this->belongsToMany(User::class)->withPivot('completed_at');
    }
}
```

My goal is to load a complete course with the following scopes on the `course` model:

```
class Course extends Model {
    // ...

    public function scopeWithModules($query) {
        return $query->with(['modules' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['user' => function ($q) { $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id); }])
              ->whereHas('user', function ($q) { $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id); });
        }]);
    }

    public function scopeWithLessons($query) {
        return $query->with(['modules.lessons' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['user' => function ($q) { $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id); }])
              ->whereHas('user', function ($q) { $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id); });
        }]);
    }

    public function scopeWithTasks($query) {
        return $query->with(['modules.tasks' => function ($q) {
            $q->with(['user' => function ($q) { $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id); }])
               ->whereHas('user', function ($q) { $q->where('user_id', auth()->user()->id); });
        }]);
    }

    // ...
}
```

Each of these scopes alone is working fine. But combining them will override the previous ones, so only the last of these scopes will be executed.

Executing this

```
$course = Course::whereSlug('learning-abc')
                ->withModules()
                ->withLessons()
                ->withTasks()
                ->firstOrFail();
```

will give me the course with modules and tasks (but no lessons and user information for the modules).

Of course I can write one single bulky scope like `withModulesLessonsTasks()` but I hope there is a more elegant solution to this. Any ideas?

---

Before I had:

```
$course = Course::whereSlug('learning-abc')
                ->with([
                        'modules.user',
                        'modules.lessons.user',
                        'modules.tasks.user'
                  ])
                ->firstOrFail();
```

which was working fine except for filtering the `auth()->user()`.

Comment: If all these scopes have to query the user, wouldn't it be easier to load the courses from the user model instead of the course model? If your user model has relations to the modules you'll be able to automatically query them from the user model.

Comment: Interesting approach. I'm not absolutely sure, if I understand you correctly. Do you mean this: `User::getCourse('learning-abc')->with(['modules', 'modules.lessons', 'modules.tasks']->firstOrFail();` Then I would still have to filter the modules for _the_ course on each _with_ relation, otherwise I would get all modules (from different courses).

Comment: Yes, something like this, I'm not entirely sure how your relations are set. `auth()->user()->courses()->first()->load(['modules', 'modules.lessons', 'modules.tasks']);`

Comment: Okay, but where do I load the user's information for the modules, lessons and tasks? E.g. the `modules()` relation will still be on the `Course` model, so the pivot table `user_module` won't be loaded?